# ndb.query.count() failed with 60s query deadline on large entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, bigtable

For 100k+ entities in google datastore, ndb.query().count() is going to cancelled by deadline , even with index. I've tried with produce_cursors options but only iter() or fetch_page() will returns cursor but count() doesn't.

How can I count large entities?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, inside a task queue. The issue isn't the 60-second `DeadlineExceededError` for front-end requests, it's the 60-second (ish?) deadline for the query itself, `_ToDatastoreError(err)...
Timeout: The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.` Well, I'm guessing that's OP's problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something that expensive you should take a look on [Task Queue Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/). Based on the Task Queue API, Google App Engine provides the [deferred library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred), which we can use to simplify the whole process of running background tasks.

Here is an example of how you could use the deferred library in your app:

```
import logging

def count_large_query(query):
  total = query.count()
  logging.info('Total entities: %d' % total)
```

Then you can call the above function from within your app like:

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

# Somewhere in your request:
deferred.defer(count_large_query, ndb.query())
```

---

While I'm still not sure if the `count()` going to return any results with such large datastore you could use this `count_large_query()` function instead, which is using cursors (untested):

```
LIMIT = 1024
def count_large_query(query):
  cursor = None
  more = True
  total = 0
  while more:
    ndbs, cursor, more = query.fetch_page(LIMIT, start_cursor=cursor, keys_only=True)
    total += len(ndbs)

  logging.info('Total entitites: %d' % total)
```

To try locally the above set the `LIMIT` to 4 and check if in your console you can see the `Total entitites: ##` line.

---

As Guido mentioned in the comment this will not going to scale either:

> This still doesn't scale (though it may postpone the problem). A task
>   has a 10 minute instead of 1 minute, so maybe you can count 10x as
>   many entities. But it's pretty expensive! Have a search for sharded
>   counters if you want to solve this properly (unfortunately it's a lot
>   of work).

So you might want to take a look on [best practices for writing scalable applications](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/overview)  and especially the [sharding counters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters).

Comment: Hm. This still doesn't scale (though it may postpone the problem). A task has a 10 minute instead of 1 minute, so maybe you can count 10x as many entities. But it's pretty expensive! Have a search for sharded counters if you want to solve this properly (unfortunately it's a lot of work).

Comment: @RayYan I updated my answer after Guido's comment.. so take that into consideration as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a frustrating issue. I've been doing some work in this area lately to get some general count stats - basically, the number of entities that satisfy some query. `count()` is a great idea, but it is hobbled by the datastore RPC timeout.

It would be nice if `count()` supported cursors somehow so that you could cursor across the result set and simply add up the resulting integers rather than returning a large list of keys only to throw them away. With cursors, you could continue across all 1-minute / 10-minute boundaries, using the "pass the baton" deferred approach. With `count()` (as opposed to `fetch(keys_only=True)`) you can greatly reduce the waste and hopefully increase the speed of the RPC calls, e.g., it takes a shocking amount of time to count to 1,000,000 using the `fetch(keys_only=True)` approach - an expensive proposition on backends.

Sharded counters are a lot of overhead if you only need/want periodic count statistics (e.g., a daily count of all my accounts in the system by, e.g., country).

Comment: The solution here is to use `db.Query.count` instead, which *does* support cursors.  It's the difference between many minutes counting and several seconds, when the count is on the order of millions.  Using `deferred.defer` to store and forward results, you can count up to 2M in two 60s requests.  Note that you can use `db.Query.count` even if you're using an `ndb` mapping.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use google app engine backends.
Backends are exempt from the 60-second deadline for user requests and the 10-minute deadline for tasks, and run indefinitely.
Please take a look at the document here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview

Comment: Thanks but even backends, query deadline 60s is not avoidable.

Comment: this is true, it's the database API that's timing out rather then the platform you are calling it from. it's unavoidable as I found on from a similar question/answer.